# Determining tree graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to make my understanding for the condition such that G is connected and has no cycles more clear. Does having cycles also contains the below example?[image]

Comment: Yes, it is a cycle. Of length 3.

Comment: So the above graph is not tree? because of cycle?

Comment: You are correct.